# basic jquery slider optimalizing for myselff

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Im making a newsfeed using the slider from http://www.basic-slider.com/    Its looking like the image, bellow. Now I wan't it to slide the image and fade the text. I don't have any idea how I would do this, (Look at the website in case you don't know what I mean.) Is there somebody with more knowledge than me and knows how to do this?

[image: Exampe]

Comment: Have u looked into the animate, jquery function, http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Yes, I did, but im using an basic slider, I don't know where to make changes, or even how to. I'm also not the best in jquery, Thats why im asking for it:)

Comment: So does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the properties in the activation javascript.  The default is fade, so add a bottom four properties below:

```
$('#banner-fade').bjqs({
 height      : 320,
 width       : 620,
 responsive  : true,
 animtype : 'slide', // accepts 'fade' or 'slide'
 animduration : 450, // how fast the animation are
 animspeed : 4000, // the delay between each slide
 automatic : true // automatic
});
```

.... ah, sorry, I realised that's only half of your question. You want to fade the text too...

EDIT -->
Add the above properties, then go to line 615 of bjqs-1.3.js and just inside the function add this line:

```
$('.bjqs-caption').fadeOut(settings.animduration);
```

Then add the following line at line 708 at the very end of that function:

```
$('.bjqs-caption').fadeIn(settings.animduration);
```

You will then have to make the same changes to the bjqs-1.3.min.js version.

When the function is called all captions are faded out the slide happens and then you fade the caption back in.

(requires further testing!)

Comment: Fade the text, and slide the image, while its in the same slider, got it now? Thanks for looking into it anyways;)